# Nice proof for $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+nh)-f(x)}{h}=nf'(x)$ besides LHR

Tags: calculus, derivatives, arithmetic

Why is $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+nh)-f(x)}{h}=nf'(x)?$$ A cheap answer would be L'Hospital's rule, but I think there should be a more direct way to prove it, appealing to the first principles of the derivative. Intuitively, it makes sense that near $x$, the function $h\mapsto f(x+h) - f(x)$ is behaving approximately linearly, and so $n(f(x+h)-f(x)) \approx f(x+nh)-f(x)$.

Anyone know of a slick way to show this?

Comment: You can just let k=nh, and then write the limit in terms of k.

Comment: @user84413 Of course!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

$$\frac{f(x+nh)-f(x)}h=n\frac{f(x+nh)-f(x)}{nh}$$

and now just use the substitution $\;k:=nh\;$ in the fraction and observe that $\;h\to 0\iff k\to 0\;$ ...